# PHP - Simple Cookie Not Saving (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to make a language cookie, but for some reason the cookie isn't saving.

here's the code I'm using

```
if ( !empty($_GET['language']) ) {
    setcookie('language-eclear', $_GET['language']);
}


if ( empty($_COOKIE['language-eclear']) ) {
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    switch ($lang){
        case "fr":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexFR.php");
            break;
        case "de":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexDE.php");
            break;
        case "en":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexEN.php");
            break;
        case "nl":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexNL.php");
            break; 
        default:
            include("langFiles/lang-indexEN.php");
            break;
    }
}else{
    $lang = $_COOKIE['language-eclear'];
    switch ($lang){
        case "fr":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexFR.php");
            break;
        case "de":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexDE.php");
            break;
        case "en":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexEN.php");
            break;
        case "nl":
            include("langFiles/lang-indexNL.php");
            break; 
        default:
            include("langFiles/lang-indexEN.php");
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

the if loop for setting the cookie works I tested it by echo'ing *$_GET['language'];*.

However it seems that the cookie isn't saving. What am I missing?

*PS: I'm using a wordpress website*

Comment: you must ensure that you don't have any browser output before the call of `setcookie()` function. otherwise browser rejects the cookie. so check for any output before that code.

Comment: @mitkosoft sorry this is my first wordpress site, but do you know where to set the cookie on a wordpress site? since I don't know where wordpress starts loading the first output

Comment: @Nikolas Decroos, it depends how the Wordpress theme is built, but in general it should be enough to be included in `functions.php` which is placed into theme root folder.

Comment: @mitkosoft Thanks, this worked perfectly!